# Ошибка org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy при парсинге

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

Столкнулся с очень странным явлением при работе компонента на сервере.
Spring Boot 2, jdk 11, компонент запущен на 2 нодах.

кусок кода где падает ошибка

```
BigDecimal o = call.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, source);
return o.longValue(); // падает вот тут
```

сам запрос к БД отрабатывает нормально и возвращает BigDecimal . Локально все отрабатывает.
Однако на сервере получаю стек

```
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62), 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), 
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205), 
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy164.createRegistryHeader(Unknown Source), 

тут вызовы методов ... 

ru.yota.finservices.rs.controller.RsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f916ce07.invoke(<generated>), 
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747), 
org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120),
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), 
 org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747), 
 org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689),
```

почему так может получаться?

Comment: А где сам текст ошибки? Где само значение BigDecimal?

Comment: хороший вопрос. в логах ничего этого нету. просто network-address:|component:|branch:|ERROR| ... далее то что привел.